# Deserialize complex json using GSON 2.2.4

Tags: android, json, gson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this complex Json using GSON 2.2.4

```
    {
    "AUSMASS": {
        "KAPITEL": [
            {
                "KAP": "102",
                "KAG": "",
                .
                .
                .
            }
        ],
        "POSITION_TEXT": [
            {
                "MANDT": "500",
                "ID": "00181171",
                .
                .
                .
            }
        ],
        "POSITION": [
           {
                "MANDT": "500",
                "ID": "00180699",
                .
                .
                .
            }
        ]
        "KONDITION": [
            {
                "MANDT": "500",
                "ID": "00180699",
                .
                .
                .
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And my POJO classes  KAPITEL, POSITIONTEXT, POSITION and KONDITION

```
public class AusmassInfo {

    @Expose
    private ArrayList<KAPITEL> KAPITEL = new ArrayList<>();
    @SerializedName("POSITION_TEXT")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<POSITIONTEXT> POSITIONTEXT = new ArrayList<>();
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<POSITION> POSITION = new ArrayList<>();
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<KONDITION> KONDITION = new ArrayList<>();


   ...Getters and Setters
}
```

and this is main POJO which includes AUSMASS ...

```
public class Example {
    @Expose
    private AusmassInfo AUSMASS;

    /**
     * @return The AUSMASS
     */
    public AusmassInfo getAUSMASS() {
        return AUSMASS;
    }

    /**
     * @param AUSMASS The AUSMASS
     */
    public void setAUSMASS(AusmassInfo AUSMASS) {
        this.AUSMASS = AUSMASS;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to deserialize in this way

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Example>>() {
            }.getType();
            bigObject = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
```

But I'm getting empty objects.

Can any body help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gson can't serialize generics lists by default. But there's a workaround, search for generic gson list on stack overflow, i remember someone posted an approach to make it work.

Another way is iterating over the json array and serializing each item.

Answer (score 0):

> The specified json is an Object not an Array.

So that use below snip of code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
bigObject = gson.fromJson(reader, Example.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's not working. I changed GSON with JACKSON and now I can archive to deserialize this nested json.